# Is this vent above a mudsill needed?

Tags: drywall, vent, stucco

I have a house built in the 60ies and there's a vent that goes above the mudsill to the cavity between the stucco and the drywall in my garage. I don't understand what is the purpose of this vent, specially when it can collect moisture from rain as it is not a louvered vent. My question is what is the purpose of this? Can, or should I close it to the exterior, as I want to replace the vent as it has a hole? I'm also repairing and painting the drywall on the inside of the garage. The house is in a concrete slab. Please note that this is not a vent to the crawlspace since it's a vent above the concrete foundation, there's a small wall from the slab up to the mudsill.

[image: Picture 1 from outside you can see the light in the garage]

[image: Drywall was a bit rotten in that corner]

[image: Vent has a hole and is not in good shape]

[image: view of vent from outside]

Answer (score 1):

Garages have vents like that to air out any fumes.  If it doesn't go through to the inside then a previous owner closed up the drywall on the inside.  If you park a gas car in the garage then cut the drywall on the inside to restore it.  Otherwise, you could close it up if you wish, but since that vent will likely be required if/when you sell the home (or decide to start parking in there again), maybe just fill the cavity with a foam block and put a louvered cover on the outside (i.e. instead of stucco'ing it closed).

Answer (score 0):

We don't know your location in the world, but homes in Florida built with garages, had those vents in the garage walls for ventilation.

This was a 50s to mid 80s thing and is not done much now.

The exception is some homes on the coast have the vents right at garage floor level to let the water out in a flood event.

If that drywall damage was over the course of 60 years, I don't think it is too high a price for some ventilation.